# Faster way to get file information

Tags: r, fileinfo

I have +100K files in a folder and need to retrieve the time information. I know that `file.info` and `file.mtime` work to get the information, but with +100K files, both function take quite a lot of time. Is there any other way to get such information spending less time? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can use the command `shell` to use system calls: if you are on a unix system, `shell('ls --full-time')` is a good start

Comment: if we are talking minutes and hours, get all the file names, write a functions that retrieves what you need probably the same you are using right now, parallezie with furrr or future

Comment: @jeremycg That will be almost certainly even slower …

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using file information at all? Fundamentally, retrieving file information will *always* be fairly slow, since it requires performing system calls, which entail context switching. The best way to speed these up is to avoid them in the first place. The next best way is to use native code which allows bunching up lots of requests to the kernel into a single system call (on POSIX systems, the `fts_read` API might be helpful).

Comment: @KonradRudolph you might be right! it depends on what exactly the op is doing and how they are finding the files to check. A reproducible example would help

Comment: Not sure what file info you need... but you could give `data.table::fread()` a go.. Using the `cmd`-argument, it can import the output of system-commands like `dir` (and all it's parameters).